# Unknown operating system

Tags: flutter, dart

While trying to run $ flutter upgrade on cmd, powershell and bash.

Result was:
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 540786dd51f112885a89792d678296b95e6622e5...
Unknown operating system. Cannot install Dart SDK.

Why it could not install Dart SDK.

Before the release of flutter 1.17 it was working well but now it couldn't install Dart SDK.

Comment: are you using cmd /powershell or gitbash

Comment: I'm using bash but I got the answer I just downloaded the flutter app again and just replace the old one. Thank you so much for the support.